# MS Access - Linking field value to column

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two tables in Access i am trying to relate:
Products & Prices.

Following is a simplified example

```
ProductCode    ProductName
  A              Sugar
  B              Salt
  C              Bread


Date           A         B         C
01/02/2016     $1       $2        $3
```

I do not want to split the prices table as follows:

```
Date           Code    Price  
01/02/2016     A       $1    
01/02/2016     B       $2
01/02/2016     C       $3
```

Excuse my ignorance, as i am new to Access.

Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the answer you expect, but here it is anyway:
Access is a **relational database**, and when using it you are supposed to follow some design rules for your tables. Search the web for "database normalisation" (eventually normali**z**ation).

For instance, your `Prices` table is not properly designed: should you ever have a 4th product, it would require modification of the table structure. A better design would be something like:

```
PriceId as AutoNumber
dtReplaced as date  'leave Null for 'active' prices
ProductCode as string
Price as Currency
```

with a PK on PriceId and Unique Index on ProductCode + dtReplaced to
avoid having 2 active prices for the same product.

Also note that `Date` is a reserved word, and should not be used as a field name, unless your are really looking for trouble.

Comment: @Fionnuala nice link. But it's so well hidden I have been unable to locate it through navigating from the top of the site.